# How to get Range between TWO dates in Asp.Net..?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, date

I have Two DatePicker in TextBox. I wants print all the dates between to range of textBox. How to insert those multiple dates in database...?

Example:

In First TextBox :- 1 July 2013

Second TextBox :- 31 December 2013

Output should be come likes :

1 July 2013

2 July 2013

3 July 2013

4 July 2013

|

|

|

30 December 2013

31 December 2013

Comment: show us some of your code

Answer (score 4):

```
 private List<DateTime> GetRange()
 {
    var res = new List<DateTime>();
    var start = DateTime.Parse(textBox1.Text);
    var end = DateTime.Parse(textBox2.Text);
    for (var date = start; date <= end; date = date.AddDays(1))
         res.Add(date);

    return res;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, convert both inputs to date object.  You can use `DateTime.Parse()` for this.

```
DateTime start = DateTime.Parse("1 July 2013");
DateTime end = DateTime.Parse("31 December 2013");
```

Then simply loop through to the end.

```
while(start <= end)
{
   // Output or save to DB etc
   Console.WriteLine(start.ToString("d MMMMM yyyy"));
   start = start.AddDays(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do this?

You can certainly do it, depending on the granularity with a varchar(max) field in the db and set the string to be:

```
string result = "";
for(int x = 0; x< (endDate - startDate).TotalDays; x++) 
{
   result += startDate.AddDays(x).ToDateString();
}
```

I can't fathom a reason why you would want this though. Store the start and end date and then use logic in the application to calculate the information as and when required would seem like it would make a lot more sense.

Comment: Because of, i want to Enter Those dates in database, at admin side so i want this type of logic @Michael

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't make sense - I mean, why store an enormous amount of text data representing dates in some arbitrary form in a database when the information is readily computable? More for interest than anything, but this doesn't seem like a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<DateTime> allDates = new List<DateTime>();

    int starting = startingDate.Day;
int ending = endingDate.Day;

for (int i = starting; i <= ending; i++)
{
    allDates.Add(new DateTime(startingDate.Year, startingDate.Month, i));
}
```

Comment: how to print it in labels ..?

Comment: Labels? If you need to print on label, instead of adding in a list, you can set the value in your labels directly.

Comment: Ans i also need week range likes........     01 July 2013 - 06 July 2013, 08 July 2013 - 13 July 2013

Answer (score 0):

using Linq:

```
var date1 = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-1);
var date2 = DateTime.Now;

var dates = Enumerable
    .Range(1, (int)(date2 - date1).TotalDays)
    .Select(d => date1.AddDays(d).Date);
```

And to dump the result to a string:

```
var output = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, dates);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks For your Response Everyone.....

but Perfect Answer for me is Combination of all above Answers...

```
DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text);

        string result = "";

       for (int x = 0; x <= (Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox2.Text) - Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text)).TotalDays; x++)

        {

            result = dt.AddDays(x).ToString("d MMMMM yyyy");

            Response.Write("<br>" + result);

        }
```