# vb.net months between two dates

Tags: vb.net, date, between

I want to display all the dates between two dates with year.

```
Eg: FromDate = 2012-01-01  ToDate=2013-05-01

Output should be : 
    January 2012
    February 2012
    March 2012
    April 2012
    ...
    May 2013
```

Thanks for any valuable inputs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854901/how-to-get-range-between-two-dates-in-asp-net

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I searched the stackoverflow but did not find this!!

Comment: You're welcome! This should give you the solution.

Comment: No I mean before posting this question, I searched the stackoverflow but did not find any answer near to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
' Start from getting date with year and month from FromDate and 1 as a day '
Dim RealFromDate = new DateTime(FromDate.Year, FromDate.Month, 1)

While RealFromDate <= EndDate
    Console.WriteLine(RealFromDate.ToString("yyyy MMM")
    RealFromDate = RealFromDate.AddMonths(1)
End While
```

Comment: Thanks for this..  I tried many other methods but could not get this output.